# when calling javasript file not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I called up javascript file with name 'main.js' but it isn't working. I inspected the file in chrome but was empty.can you help me, please

this is the javascript file below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

this is the functions file

```
<?php 
    function add_style(){
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css');
    }

    function add_script(){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5shiv.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5shiv.js');
        wp_script_add_data('html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
        wp_enqueue_script('respond', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/respond.min.js');
        wp_script_add_data('respond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
        wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
    }
    function add_navbar(){

        register_nav_menus(array(
            'navbar-menu' => 'navbar menu',
            'footer-menu' => 'footer menu'
        ));
    }
    function bootstrap_menu(){
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'navbar-menu',
            'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav mr-auto'
        ));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_style');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script');
    add_action('init', 'add_navbar');
```

Comment: Is there any Error showing in Chrome DevTools Console?

Comment: Have you confirmed the file is in the theme js folder (e.g. it wasn't added to the css folder with main.css by mistake). Does the link appear correctly in the HTML? Also, have you tried changing the handle from "main" in case it is already in use elsewhere?

Comment: I have tried to put the file outside js folder and have tried to rename the file and  confirmed the file is in the theme js folder but the problem not solved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to enqueue jQuery, it's already added in WordPress. You can find a list of libraries included in WordPress in the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

2. `$` is not supported by default while using jQuery with WordPress.
   You can use one of the following methods to use `$` with jQuery

---

```
(function($) {
    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);
})( jQuery );
```

OR

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);
});
```